# Relationship between probability spaces and topological spaces

Tags: probability, general-topology, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I know that a space with an inner product are subset of normed spaces, which are subset of metric spaces, which are subset of topological spaces.
My question is:
What is the relationship of a probability space with all these other spaces?

Comment: Topological spaces are very natural for defining measurable spaces. Once you have a topology, you can define the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ which contains all open sets of the topology, hence giving you a measurable space. Then you simply define a probability measure of your choice, yielding a probability space.

Comment: Ok, so a probability space is a topological space but not a metric space?

Comment: No, what i am saying is that a topological space *can be turned* into a measurable space / probability space. However, that doesn't mean there is a way to view a general measurable space / probability space as a topological/metric space.

Comment: None of those are "subsets". Metric space is not a topological space. It induces a topology, but it is more than that, in particular multiple different metrics often induce the same topology. And a probability spaces, or more generally measurable spaces are of their own kind.